# Is there a GOTO command in Ampscript?

Tags: email, ampscript

I'm working on a section of code that creates coupons in our emails.  We're pulling the coupon number that we want to use from a data extension `@de_send`.  We have a second data extension `@de_coupon` that has all of the information to be populated into the coupon.  We use a key `@coupnum` that exists in both data extensions to correlate who gets what coupon.  I'm looking to avoid a possible error where the person in `@de_send` has a blank value in `@coupnum`.

Essentially what I want to do is skip a whole section of ampscript code if the value is blank, however due to the complexity of the nested if-else statements we're already using I'd like to set an `if empty(@coupnum) then {goto end}` statement.

I realize if I set `if not empty(@coupnum) then` I can put all the code I want to skip inside that if-else, but I have to make sure that the `else endif` doesn't get removed accidentally at the end by someone editing the block.

Long story short does anyone know of any other way to execute a "goto" command in Ampscript?

Simplified Concept:

```
SET @sendRowset = LOOKUPROWS(@de_send, "email", emailaddr)
if ROWCOUNT(@sendRowset) > 0 then
  set @desendrow = ROW(@sendRowset, 1)
  set @coupnum = FIELD(@desendrow, "coupnum")
  /* other variables etc. */
else /* not in list */
  var @coupnum /* set to null */
endif

/* goto command here */
if empty(@coupnum) then {goto end}
else
  /* rest of very extensive coupon code here */
endif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there isn't. However as far as I understand your use case the else-part isn't necessary, so your block could look like this:

```
if not empty(@coupnum) then
    /* Your code to skip if @coupnum is empty */
endif
```

Validation should also fail if the endif is removed, so accidentally removing it should be easy to identify. Adding a comment to the endif which includes information about the corresponding if-statement should also reduce the risk of accidentally removing the statement.

*Additional note:* goto-statements are generally a pretty bad thing to use as the flow of complex scripts/programs is harder to follow for other developers in the future.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not a huge fan of goto either, but we'll be nested about 5 if-thens deep at some points of the code if I wrap the whole coupon code in another if statement.  sounds like that's the best option though.  Thanks for the answer!